What caused Sky News to transmit a grainy image following the 2024 Crowdstrike outage?
The following video appears to show the video signal of the Sky News TV broadcast suddenly lose graphical quality: 


The title of the video suggests that this is due to the 2024 CrowdStrike incident.
The news broadcast appears to be live, at 23:42 in local time (Milwaukee, Wisconsin). According to Wikipedia, the faulty update was distributed at 23:09 local time, that day.
Could the grainy signal be a coincidence, or was it caused by the incident?
It seems only the camera signal from the reporter is affected, not any of the other elements of the broadcast, like the text.
Are we seeing a digital signal falling back on an analogue one? If so, why are both being transmitted simultaneously, from the reporter's video camera?

"digital signal falling back on an analogue one" pretty sure this isn't a thing. Also, the graphics are definitely affected.

i deleted my answer as I have not yet found anything to prove otherwise, only that it seems to be fake. All other information points to the outage being the blue screens and text/autocue/software not running. Theres no such thing as a analogue fallback for digital, its either one or it isnt, and data failure in digital video doesnt look like that. It was widely reported that SN (Aus) on foxtel switched to Fox, which it does here, but no where is there mention of such video effects. I did work in studios and if we have a problem, we put up a card which many channels did.

AFAIK, it's fake, effect added in post.
There is no digital fallback to analogue, the latter is gone.
The camera is in a studio and a broadcast problem would not result in this. I did work in studios and even in the analogue days this wouldn't go out, if it were the case.
I haven't seen any other footage like this either. Sky News does not reference any visual issues either, only the blue screens presented here and in other news articles around the world (result of software update and restart, none of which would affect video quality, in this manner).
If you look at the channel that this video comes from, two further videos are published during the crowd strike incident and they are broadcast (and recorded) normally. As in all other cases related to crowd strike, the most obvious thing is the blue screen, not video effects…

CrowdStrike effects discussed on Sky News



If you see the screen behind, because everything is digital, you either get the picture, or not. There's no fall-back.


It seems only the camera signal from the reporter is affected, not any of the other elements of the broadcast, like the text.

As explained in the real news articles about this:
Onscreen graphics such Tickertape, time, etc, and also autocue in the studio, were not functioning even while the picture and sound were broadcast.
So if really affected by the outage, you would not see the screen as it is in the video and you would not have unaffected onscreen graphics. Simply put, everything would be affected, and when this happens, they put a static card up instead:


Are we seeing a digital signal falling back on an analogue one? If so, why are both being transmitted simultaneously, from the reporter's video camera?

First of all, theres no fallback, as from digital to analogue for broadcast tv. In basic terms theres a switcher, with multiple inputs. The final output is what you get on your screen, so if there was a problem locally (say, on location) the problem would only be there. This was said to be much more widespread so the 'issues' would actually affect everything, including text on screen.
